# appending HTML codes to an elements using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code for append a row to an existing table

```js
$('#factorTable').append('<tr id="ft-' + id + '"><td id="ftn-' + id + '">' + name + '</td><td id="ftp-' + id + '">' + price + '</td><td id="ftNum-' + id + '">' + number + '</td><td id="ftSum-' + id + '">' + sum + '</td></tr>');
```

But I need to do it without using jQuery. How can I convert it to only native javascript I know that I can insert a row to a table using this code :

```js
// Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

However, as you see in my jQuery code, I need to add `id` to `<td>` and `<tr>` tags.

Comment: `cell1.id='id here'`

Comment: or `row.innerHTML='<td id="ftn-' + id + '">' + name + '</td><td id="ftp-' + id + '">' + price + '</td><td id="ftNum-' + id + '">' + number + '</td><td id="ftSum-' + id + '">' + sum + '</td>'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you don't need to support IE8 or IE9**, you can use `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('factorTable').insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    '<tr id="ft-' + id + '"><td id="ftn-' + id + '">' + name + '</td><td id="ftp-' + id + '">' + price + '</td><td id="ftNum-' + id + '">' + number + '</td><td id="ftSum-' + id + '">' + sum + '</td></tr>'
);
```

But [caniuse says](http://caniuse.com/#feat=insertadjacenthtml) that IE8 and IE9

> (Throw) an "Invalid target element for this operation." error when called on a table, tbody, thead, or tr element.

As you're inserting a `tr` with `td`s in it, I assume you're calling this on a `tbody`.

If you need IE9 (or earlier) support, we need to fall back on `createElement`:

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr').
tr.id = 'ft-' + id;
tr.innerHTML = '<td id="ftn-' + id + '">' + name + '</td><td id="ftp-' + id + '">' + price + '</td><td id="ftNum-' + id + '">' + number + '</td><td id="ftSum-' + id + '">' + sum + '</td>';
document.getElementById('factorTable').appendChild(tr);
```